# How can I more customize wordpress tags list?

Tags: wordpress, tags, customization, taglist

I get a code wordpress codex

```
<?php the_tags( '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ); ?>
```

for show/style tags list.

But I also need to add `<a href="#"></a>`

My HTML is this,

```
<ul class="tag-list">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>fully responsive</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>localisation support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>semantic and clean html/css</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>woocomerce support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>custom widgets</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks,
Dipto

Comment: Im not too sure exactly what the question is asking. Do you want to add more tags or is there a problem with the links?

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure to understand well your question. 
If you need WP to generate tags list HTML like *your* HTML, you can do it like this :

```
<?php the_tags( '<ul class="tag-list"> <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>', '</a></li> <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>', '</a></li></ul>' ); ?>
```